# Custom validation failing even when data filled in

Tags: c#, validation

I have created a custom validation rule that requires two textboxes if and only if the previous set of radio buttons shows `Yes` selected.  Validation works fine if no radio selection or `No` is made, but fails when `Yes` is selected, if when data is supplied.

My custom validation is:

```
public class DamageSupport : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var incidentdetail = (IncidentDetail) validationContext.ObjectInstance;

        return (incidentdetail.PropertyDamage == "Y") ? new ValidationResult("This field is required since Property Damage is set to 'Yes'") : ValidationResult.Success;

    }
}
```

Here are my modelvalidation rules:

```
    [MaxLength(1)]
    [Display(Name = "Property Damaged?")]
    public string PropertyDamage { get; set; }

    [RegularExpression(@"^\d+.\d{0,2}$")]
    [Range(0, 99999999.99)]
    [Display(Name = "Estimated value of damage")]
    [DamageSupport]
    public decimal? DamageAmount { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Description of the damage")]
    [DamageSupport]
    public string DamageDescription { get; set; }
```

I look at the data in the ModelState object data in debug mode, and all the data I types is there,just fails validation for some reason.

I double checked it wasn't a data type issue by removing the custom validation and saving the same data, works fine.

Anyone think of someplace for me to look?

Comment: Look at your `return` statement. Where do you actually check whether the value is non-empty?

Comment: @Blorgbeard - Thanks!  Obvious miss on my part.  Was so concerned about checking value of teh radio button, forgot to check the value of the input field itself.